# Angular - component visibility toggle not working

Tags: angular

I've set up a simple app, consisting of two components: the main app and a banner.  Banner is rendered within the app component and the idea is to toggle the visibility of the banner from the dashboard component.

The above works well the first time (i.e the banner is shown, then hidden) but on subsequent attempts, the banner remains hidden.  Below is the code:

app.compoenent.html

```
<app-banner [showAlert]="showAlert" [alertMessage]="alertMessage"></app-banner>

<button (click)="onClick()">Apply</button>
```

app.compoenent.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { BannerComponent } from './components/banner/banner.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  showAlert: boolean = false;
  alertMessage: string = '';

  onClick() {
    this.alertMessage = 'Banner Message';
    this.showAlert = true;
  }
}
```

banner.compoenent.html

```
<div [hidden]="!showAlert">
    <div>
        <span>
            {{alertMessage}}
        </span>
        <a class="close" (click)="closeAlert()" style="text-decoration: underline">[close]</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

banner.compoenent.ts

```
import {Component, HostBinding, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.scss']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() alertMessage!: string;
    @Input() showAlert: boolean = false;
    @Input() open() {
        this.showAlert = true;
    }

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    closeAlert(): void {
        this.showAlert = false;
    }
}
```

In the above example, when the button is clicked, the following code is executed in app.component.ts:

```
this.alertMessage = 'error';
this.showAlert = true;
```

This correctly shows the banner div.  The banner component contains a link tag for which the event handler sets the showAlert property to false to hide the banner div - again this also works as expected.

However, now if the button in the app component is clicked again for a second time, even though the showAlert property is being set to true again, the banner remains hidden.

A Stackblitz has ben setup to demonstrate:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9sadyj

Can't see where i'm going wrong, any insight would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

**The issue:**

At the moment your are just hiding the alert. So it never gets recreated, but rather stays in the DOM. This way it never gets passed new values from the dashboard component, as far as the dashboard is concerned it did its job.

**A solution:**

Just render your banner conditionally on a boolean in your dashboard component, to take it out of the DOM entirely and add it again:

In dashboard.component.ts:

```js
showBanner = true
```

In the dashboard template:

```html
<app-banner *ngIf="showBanner" [alertMessage]="alertMessage"></app-banner>
```

And then just flip that boolean with any logic:

For instance an @Output emitting an event.

Here's a working example for you on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qjgjek?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

**Some notes:**

The way you are trying to hide the element only works when you move the 'showAlert'-logic to the child component, and only part of the component will be hidden (not the button).

But even then I would use "display:none;" over "visibility:hidden;" so there would be no dead space on the page.

Comment: Let me know if you need more help with the logic of flipping that boolean. Also, if you create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) we can more easily help you with your code. Cheers

Comment: I originally had an *ngIf ondition on the app banner tag as in your example, but when setting it to false, the div html would disappear from the DOM and again, I would not be able to show it again.  I'll set up a stackblitz and add the link top my question shortly.

Comment: Question edited to include the stackblitz demo

Comment: I added a working example on Stackblitz for you.

Comment: This works, thanks.  However I was wondering if it would be possible to take care of the closing of the banner from within the banner component itself?  I would then not need to create a close event for the banner in every component which uses it.

Comment: For this you can use a 'template' and add / remove it from the DOM. You could also use a directive. This is a little more complex though. I will address this later, but you could already look into it. This is also starting to look a lot like a toast now, you could also add a toast library and style the toast to look how you want, because you will want a lot of it's functionality, like a setting to never display multiple alerts for example.